# Excel default Find by columns, not rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

When using a particular workbook in Excel I want the default `Find` to `Search By Columns`, not `By Rows` (which seems to be the immutable default).

If I manually make that change in the `Find` `Options` it will remain for the duration of that Excel process.  How can I programmatically set that option?

[image: Excel Find/Replace Window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following macro will set the `Find` defaults in the background – [arguments documented here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find):

```
Sub SetFindByColumns()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Cells.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
End Sub
```

Having defined that in a module, adding the following call in the `ThisWorkbook` object will  trigger it as soon as the workbook is opened:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SetFindByColumns
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the best sort of question - when OPs are guided to the answer, solves it for themselves and then posts their own answer back to the community. Go ahead and checkmark your own solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is seemingly no Excel setting or registry edit that allows you to customize the default Find behavior. What is apparent is that Find behavioral settings are remembered per active Excel instance or session - that is, as long as Excel is open the Find settings will be remembered once you change them. You can abuse this fact by writing a small VBA macro that does a search as soon as Excel starts. This find can be executed in VBA code either via the find dialogue box or the VBA cells.find method. A caveat here is that certain settings like "Within" workbook/sheet does not seem to be configurable via VBA. I think the "Search" by rows/columns can be set via VBA but I am not 100% sure.

Step by step implementation of this solution is covered in several articles if you search for "excel default find and replace settings", such as this one:

`https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008802_Changing_Default_Search_Settings.html`

What the article doesn't mention is how to get the macro executing every time you open any workbook. For that purpose you must add your macro to your personal.xlsb file. The use of personal.xlsb is covered in several online resources including those by Microsoft directly. For your convenience see this article:

`https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/create-a-personal-macro-workbook-personal-xlsb`

Comment: This is a link-only answer. If the links go bad, the answer is useless. Please describe in the answer what the solution is and use the links only for illustration.

Comment: Also, that doesn't really solve the problem.  `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaFind).Show , 1, 2` will open a find dialog box with the desired defaults, but then the user has to close it manually.

Comment: @feetwet, if you use the cells.find VBA method, it still executes the same find command in the background as through the dialogue and adjusts the same find settings.

Comment: So it does!  I was able to [get that working and trigger it on opening a workbook](https://superuser.com/a/1641406/297822).